# MCUFriend LCD on Pi2

Tags: screen

I have a mcufriend.com 3.5" LCD screen which works fine on my old Pi but shows just a white screen when connected to a pi2.  Is there any way to get this screen working on the Pi2?

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about [this](http://diprofinfiniti.com/3-setting-lcd-module-pi-tft-3-6-inch-for-raspberry-pi-display-screen-mcufriend) screen I'm afraid there is no drivers available for it.  I've asked a similar question on the RaspberryPi.org forum a while ago but the question was left unanswered though.

I've also tried to rewire, but no avail.  I'm afraid your LCD will have to stay married to your old Pi.

Comment: But the OP says, it worked with his old Rpi.

Comment: @dastaan, you're right: mine also works fine on a Pi Model A and B but not on the Pi2.  I've found [elsewhere](http://diprofinfiniti.com/3-setting-lcd-module-pi-tft-3-6-inch-for-raspberry-pi-display-screen-mcufriend) that it indeed isn't compatible with the Pi2.